# Need to exclude apache httpcomponent from jboss 6.4 module

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-eap-6

We have recently migrated from **jboss 6.1 eap** to **6.4 eap**, but facing problem of class loading.

In my project lib We need to use apache **httpcore 4.4.1**, but **apache httpcore 4.3.3** is included in **6.4.**  This previously wasn't a problem when we were using **jboss 6.1** because the resteasy-jaxrs module.xml did not export httpcore library.

Now with jboss 6.4 we are getting exception :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

Its because runtime my project is using jar available from jboss and which does not having this method with required signature.

Now I want to force my application to not to use jboss jar and use jar available from web-inf/lib folder.

I have try to exclude this via jboss-deployment-structure.xml but somehow it is not working and still it is using jar from jboss only.

below is snap from the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file.

```
<deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.httpcomponents" />
        </exclusions>

         <dependencies>
             module name="org.apache.httpcomponents" />
        </dependencies>
</deployment>
```

Can someone please help me on this what is missing here or is there any alternative for this...

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using JBoss EAP, you can apply the CP07 patch for EAP 6.4 (so your version would be JBoss EAP 6.4.7) where this issue has been addressed. I would highly recommend applying the CP07 patch.

Alternatively, you can set `<module name="org.apache.httpcomponents" export="false"/>` in the `$JBOSS_MODULES\org\jboss\resteasy\resteasy-jaxrs\main\module.xml`.

However, I would recommend applying the patch as the recommended solution. This way you will not modify the configuration that is shipped with the product.

Comment: Adding other modules in exclusion and dependencies works, I wonder why it doesn't work for org.apache.httpcomponents. I want to avoid changes to Jboss. Is there a work around to avoid changes to Jboss?

Comment: Make sure you are on the latest version of EAP 6.4.z (ie. 6.4.19).

Comment: Hi @CoolBeans, We don't have option to upgrade Jboss. We are using EAP 6.4.0

Comment: @VinayakDornala I am not sure what you mean. You can always apply the latest cumulative patch via the patch cli command or from management console. You have two options - 1) manually change the resteasy-jaxrs module xml file or 2) upgrade to the latest 6.4.19 version (this bug was addressed in 6.4.8 build if I recall correctly so 6.4.19 will include the fix).

Comment: Thanks @CoolBeans, Using CLI is one option to apply the patch. I wonder why adding <module name="org.apache.httpcomponents" /> in jboss-deployment-structure.xml doesn't work?  Which is much easier solution. Also I had similar issue for other module (IMS connector) which got resolved by just updating  jboss-deployment-structure.xml

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the issue we can take one of the below approach.

1. Change $JBOSS_MODULES\org\jboss\resteasy\resteasy-jaxrs\main\module.xml 
   as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35286876/need-to-exclude-apache-httpcomponent-from-jboss-6-4-module/36482047#36482047) by [CoolBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/289171/coolbeans).
2. You can use below option if you have no control(or not authorized) to update the Jboss server configuration.

Add below xml configuration in your **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** file

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="resteasy"/>
            <subsystem name="jaxrs"/>
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding 
            some dependencies -->
        <exclusions>


            <module name="javax.ws.rs.api"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-atom-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-cdi" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxb-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jsapi" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-multipart-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.async-http-servlet-30" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jettison-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-spring" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-yaml-provider" />


        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>


        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

This worked for me, Hope this will work for other